# How to use DirectoryEntry("IIS://Localhost/W3SVC") to change IP address with several host header entries

Tags: c#, .net, iis-6

I'm trying to programmatically change the IP of a website running on Server 2003.
When I run the following code, the site binding itself gets changed, but there are other host header values that need to be changed.  How do I change those?

```
protected static void ChangeServerIP(string old_ip, string new_ip)
    {
        int siteChangedCount = 0;
        DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("IIS://LocalHost/W3SVC");

        if (entry != null)
        {
            foreach (DirectoryEntry site in entry.Children)
            {
                if (site.SchemaClassName == "IIsWebServer")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Server Binding: " + site.Properties["ServerBindings"][0].ToString());

                    if (site.Properties["ServerBindings"][0].ToString().Contains(old_ip))
                    {
                        string ServerComment = site.Properties["ServerComment"].Value.ToString();

                        Console.WriteLine("Changing " + ServerComment + "'s IP address from " + old_ip + " to " + new_ip);

                        site.Properties["ServerBindings"].Value = site.Properties["ServerBindings"][0].ToString().Replace(old_ip, new_ip);

                        site.CommitChanges();
                        siteChangedCount++;
                        Console.WriteLine("New IP address bound to site: " + ServerComment + " IP: " + site.Properties["ServerBindings"].Value.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try assigning the value to the first item in the PropertyValueCollection?

```
site.Properties["ServerBindings"][0].Value = site.Properties["ServerBindings"][0].ToString().Replace(old_ip, new_ip);
```